Incorrect comparison result with calculated date
The initial date I have is on a bad format. So i break it down to find the day, month and year.
afterwards I concatenate it. the concatenated cell has date format. then I compare this date to another one. I get incorrect result. When I substistute the calculated value of the date by typing it manually, I get the correct result. what can I do?
I tried a workaround by typing the date manually and the comparison worked correctly

Can you [edit] in all the formulas you are using? When you type a date in format DD/MM/YYY for example, excel will see it as a number; when you concatenate it, excel will see it in text format. It might be fixed by using `VALUE(). but it's unclear from just your current text, where the problem really lies.

How did that date end up in your Excel file, did you open a CSV file by any chance? See https://jkp-ads.com/articles/importtext.asp

For that who closed the question. Most narrow-focused questions are clear for specialists only, and they can help. I guess it should not be the reason to close a question. Usually, lack of details is fulfilled in answer(s) or comments.

To get the date as the DateTime value, use the Date function:
DATE(year,month,day)

Then it will be comparable with another DateTime value.
When you extract and concatenate the year, the month, and the day, you get the date as string. You can compare DateTime as string following some rules.
Here you can find more hints how to process your data.
For your sample, use:
=LET(d;TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(M9;" ");1;1);"/");DATE(INDEX(d;1;3);INDEX(d;1;1);INDEX(d;1;2)))


